# Setting up systemctl for uwsgi

Tags: linux, uwsgi, systemd

I'm trying to set up `uwsgi` service as `/etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/uwsgi/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
# Requires systemd version 211 or newer
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When trying to start it, I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:~$ sudo systemctl start emperor.uwsgi.service
Job for emperor.uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status emperor.uwsgi.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is the output for when I checked the status:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:~$ sudo systemctl status emperor.uwsgi.service
● emperor.uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Stopped uWSGI Emperor.
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor...
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: Main process exited, code=exited
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: Service hold-off time over, sche
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Stopped uWSGI Emperor.
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: Start request repeated too quick
Jan 30 11:16:05 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
```

Comment: with all due respect this is a programming question I'm setting up uwsgi to work with django and in my debugging proccess I saw it fit to setup systemctl so I can start and stop uwsgi and also views processes running under it

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar issues.  It seems `systemd` swallows some output when failing to start a (UWSGI) service.  Here are a couple of things to check to figure out what's causing the issue:

1. Check systemd journal: `journalctl -b -u $service`
2. Try to run the service manually: simply run the cmdline specified after `ExecStart=` in the systemd service file; so in your example: `/root/uwsgi/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini`

Either of these should shed some light as to whether the service fails to start.

Comment: Checking `journalctl -b -u uwsgi` helped debug and solved one issue with service setup. Great. Thanks for the tip.